# How to enum error code and message Integrate with Custom Execption

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception

I have `enum` class `ErrorCode` which has ID and message, as follows:

```
public enum ErrorCode {

    SECURITYCODE_NOT_PROVIDED(452, "security code required"),
    
    CARD_ALREADY_EXIST_FOR_USERID(453,"Card Number already exist for provided userId");

    private final int id;
    private final String message;

    ErrorCode(int id, String message) {
        this.id = id;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

I need to create custom RuntimeException and pass ErrorCode to that construcor and get output response as follows,When **securityCode** is empty need to trow that custom exception

**Controller class**

```
 @RequestMapping("/api/user")
    @RestController
    public class UserController {
    
    @PostMapping("/add")
        public ResponseEntity<?> add(
                @RequestParam("userId") long userId, @RequestParam("userName") String userName,
                @RequestParam("securityCode") String securityCode) throws CustomException{
            
            User user= userService.add(userId, userName, securityCode);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }
```

**Service class**

```
public User add(userId, userName, securityCode) throws CustomException {
    if(!user.securityCode.isEmpty() && user.securityCode.equals !=""){
        //implementation
    }
    else{
        threw new CustomException(SECURITYCODE_NOT_PROVIDED);
    }
}
```

expected reponse:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1550987372934,
    "status": 452,
    "error": "security code required",
    "exception": "com.app.exception.CustomException",
    "message": "security code required",
    "path": "/api/user/add"
}
```

Can we implement something like this

Comment: What is meant to produce this output? Calling a method on `CustomException`?

Comment: An exception basically contains an error message and a stack trace. Is class `java.lang.Throwable` an ancestor of class `CustomException`? If it is, then its constructor needs to call its superclass constructor in order to get the stack trace. Class `CustomException` has a constructor that takes a single parameter of type `ErrorCode`, i.e. your `enum`. Does that constructor call an appropriate superclass constructor? Also, do you want the error message to appear as in your question (below where you wrote _My expectation:_) ?

Comment: @Abra  edited my question and  hope now that is clear

Answer (score 0):

1.Create a custom exception wrapper by extending `ResponseStatusException` class. sample;

```
public class CustomException extends ResponseStatusException {

public CustomException (ErrorCode errorCode) {
   super(errorcode.getId(),errorCode.getMessage());
}

 public CustomException (ErrorCode errorCode, Exception ex) {
   super(errorcode.getId(),errorCode.getMessage(),ex);
}
}
```

If you need more power over your exceptions;

1. create a class and add `@ControllerAdvice` to handle all the exception Globally by extending `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`.
2. handle your `CustomException` using `@ExceptionHandler(CustomException.class)` and implement the method.

You can simply skip the 2 and 3 parts as you're throwing `ResponseStatusException` type on your Spring boot app,, it will automatically catch the exception and throw it accordingly. You can read more about this from [LINK1](https://namila007.medium.com/build-a-complete-restful-service-using-springboot-2-0-and-gradle-e9e381a114d8) and [LINK2](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring)

Comment: @musni have you tried this?